# Updatedb does not add new files

Tags: linux, azure, centos7, cifs

I have set up a separate mlocate database to index a custom directory, it is updated by a cron task, but for some reason it does not index files created since the fist time the database was created. The indexed directory is located on a `cifs` mount, but I have removed `cifs` from `PRUNEFS` in `/etc/updatedb.conf`

Here is the command that runs hourly:

```
/usr/bin/updatedb -l0 -U /datadrive/data -o /tmp/locate.db
```

If I remove `/tmp/locate.db` and run the updatedb command then all the files are indexed properly. If I run it again then files newer than the original `/tmp/locate.db` are not indexed.

This runs on a Centos 7 VM in Azure and the `cifs` mount is an `Azure Files` share. It's mounted in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

> //my_storage.file.core.windows.net/my_files /datadrive cifs vers=3.0,username=my_username,password=my_password,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0

So the question is - how do I make it index new files?

Answer (score 0):

You need update your database firstly by using `updatedb`. You could modify your script like below:

```
/usr/bin/updatedb; /usr/bin/updatedb -l0 -U /home/shui/data -o /tmp/locate.db
```

I test in my lab, it works for me.

```
[root@shui tmp]# ls -alt locate.db
-rw-r-----. 1 root slocate 164858 Apr 27 03:58 locate.db
[root@shui tmp]# updatedb 
[root@shui tmp]# updatedb -l0 -U /home/shui/data -o /tmp/locate.db
[root@shui tmp]# ls -alt locate.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 159136 Apr 27 04:07 locate.db
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: It works for me. The `locate.db` size does not change?

Comment: It doesn't. Is your `/home/shui/data` on a cifs share? I believe that's my problem.

Comment: Yes, `/home/shui` on a Azure file Share. It is a cifs share.

Comment: If I remove `/tmp/locate.db` before indexing then it finds all the files.

Comment: Do you try add 'cifs' to `PRUNEFS` on `updated.conf`. It seems work for me.